# How can I force Maven clean install to only show the summary of build?

Tags: maven

The `-q` option is a bit too quiet for me, only shows debug and errors.

Is there any way I can force Maven to output only the summary?

ie:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] project ........................................... SUCCESS [  2.437 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:30 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-15T10:35:15-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 221M/1383M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will *work*:

```
(mvn clean install -l temp.build.log; grep -B 1 -A 500 Reactor\ Summary temp.build.log; rm temp.build.log)
```